# How to pick a random number every time something happens

Tags: python, random, pygame

I'm making a pygame where the blocks descend from the top of the screen and you have to avoid them. There are three lanes you can be in and the block will fall from one of these lanes, my question is how to pick a random number every time the block passes the edge of the screen. I've tried redoing a variable as in

```
if enemy.y > 800:
    j = random.random()
    if j > .7:
        do this...
```

But it doesn't redo the choosing random number so I'm trying to find something that does. Thanks :)

Comment: The code is correct, your problem must be somewhere else.

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. What do you mean with "redoing"? Do you want to execute that in a loop maybe?

Comment: why would you want to redo the random generation?

Comment: Can we please see more code? From what you describe this should perfectly work. How many tries to you take? Could it be that you were just unlucky that two or three times in a row the same number was "drawn"?

Comment: Are you seeding the random number generator?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the enemy is just out of the screen. So add `enemy.y = 0` if enemy is out of screen. Like this:

```
if enemy.y > 800:
    enemy.y = 0#<--add this
    j = random.random()
    if j > .7:
        do this...
```